# RSA алгоритм, проблема с расшифровкой

Tags: rsa

Написан код для создания алгоритма шифрования RSA. По заданию необходимо зашифровать и расшифровать введенное слово (на англ. языке)
P и Q выбираются случайно из заданного диапазона простых чисел
Шифрует нормально, корректно не расшифровывает, в чём может быть проблема?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int vpch (int eiler, int n)
{
    int t;
    int e = 2;
    for (e = 2; e < n; )
    {
        int count = 0;
        t = 2;

        for (int j = 0; j < e; j++)
        {
        if ( eiler % t == 0 && e % t == 0)  count = count + 1;
        t++;
        }
        if (count > 0) e++;
        else break;
    } 
    return e;
}

unsigned long int stepen (long a, int b)
{
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        result = result * a;
    }

return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian_Russia.1251");

    //выбор простого числа из списка


    int prosto[11] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31};
    int e;
    int n;
    int k;
    int d;
    int eiler;
    int result = 1;   
    string name;
    string changed;
    string alphabit;

    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
    {
        alphabit = alphabit + i;
    }

    srand(time(NULL)); //сброс счётчика для выбора случайного числа
    int p = prosto[rand()%11];
    cout<<"p = "<<p<<'\n';

    srand(time(NULL)); //сброс счётчика для выбора случайного числа
    int q = prosto[rand()%11];
    cout<<"q = "<<q<<'\n';

    n = p * q;
    cout<<"n = "<<n<<'\n';
    eiler = (p-1)*(q-1);
    cout<<"eiler = "<<eiler<<'\n';


    //взаимно простые числа
    e = vpch(eiler, n);
    cout<<"e = "<<e<<'\n';


    //секретный ключ d

    d = 1; 
    do 
    {
      if ( (d*e)%eiler == 1 ) break;
      else d++;       
    }
    while ( (d*e)%eiler != 1 );
    cout<<"d = "<<d<<'\n';


    cout<<"Введите фамилию: ";
    cin>>name;
    unsigned long int rsa [name.length()][4];



    //поиск номера символа в алфавите
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < alphabit.length(); j++)
        {
            if (name[i] == alphabit[j]) rsa[i][0] = j;
        }

        rsa[i][1] = (stepen(rsa[i][0], e))%n;
        rsa[i][2] = (stepen(rsa[i][1], d))%n;
        cout<<rsa[i][0]<<"  "<<rsa[i][1]<<"  "<<rsa[i][2]<<'\n';
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` и `q` выбираются случайно? Они равны, потому что вы инициируете счетчик случайных чисел одним и тем же временем. Для RSA они должны быть разные.

RSA не может зашифровать число больше чем `eiler`, если выберутся небольшие числа, вы не сможете расшифровать результат, например 3 и 5. Коды символов больше чем 15.

Функция `stepen` может считать неверно из-за переполнения.

Comment: я убирал из кода генераторы, прописывал p и q отдельно, брал самые маленькие значения, 2 и 3. Расшифровка всё равно неверна. То есть остается вариант с тем, что формула считает неверно из-за переполнения. Вопрос в том, как это исправить

Comment: Считать сразу a^b mod n. На каждой итерации цикла делать: result = result * a % n